# Understanding the example of sensitivity analysis in Documentation using ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

There is an example in Documentation for studying sensitivity analysis, using `ParametricNDSolve`:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y''[t] + a y[t] == 0, y[0] == b, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 20}, {a, b}]
```

Then one has sensitivity concerning $a$ as

```
Plot[Evaluate[(y[1, 1][t] + {0, .1, -.1} D[y[a, 1], a][t] /. a -> 1) /. sol], {t, 0, 20}, Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]
```

[image]

I don't completely get the meaning of this plot. To gain a better understanding, I want to apply the same method to my own system:

```
s = NDSolve[{p'[t] == -gamma p[t] f[t], f'[t] == -c f[t] + gamma p[t] f[t], 
 T'[t] == b (1 - T[t]) (r^n/(f[t]^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T[t]) - m (f[t]^n/(f[t]^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T[t]), 
p[0] == p0, f[0] == f0, T[0] == T0} /. {gamma -> 0.5431799751931238`, b -> 0.08850801132176628`, 
m -> 0.9780307913586779`, r -> 0.8264557187463307`, n -> 14.983207992804674`, 
c -> 0.006, p0 -> 0.8`, f0 -> 0.001, T0 -> 0.8`}, {p, f, T}, {t, 0, 72}];
```

Now, let's consider $c$ in the above system as a parameter, removing its given value of $0.006$, and writing the system with `ParametricNDSolve`:

```
s2 = ParametricNDSolve[{p'[t] == -gamma p[t] f[t], f'[t] == -c f[t] + gamma p[t] f[t], 
T'[t] == b (1 - T[t]) (r^n/(f[t]^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T[t]) - m (f[t]^n/(f[t]^n + r^n)) (1 - 0.00262/T[t]), 
p[0] == p0, f[0] == f0, T[0] == T0} /. {gamma -> 0.5431799751931238`, b -> 0.08850801132176628`, 
m -> 0.9780307913586779`, r -> 0.8264557187463307`, n -> 14.983207992804674`, 
p0 -> 0.8`, f0 -> 0.001, T0 -> 0.8`}, {p, f, T}, {t, 0, 72}, c]
```

Now, if one wants to obtain a similar plot to the Documentation one, one has:

```
Plot[Evaluate[(T[1, 1][t] + {0, .1, -.1}  D[T[c, 1], c][t] /. c -> 0.006) /. s2], {t, 0, 72}, Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]
```

But nothing is returned. Where have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

s2 = ParametricNDSolve[{p'[t] == -gamma  p[t]  f[t], 
     f'[t] == -c  f[t] + gamma  p[t]  f[t], 
     T'[t] == b  (1 - T[t])  (r^n/(f[t]^n + r^n))  (1 - 0.00262/T[t]) - 
       m  (f[t]^n/(f[t]^n + r^n))  (1 - 0.00262/T[t]), p[0] == p0, f[0] == f0,
      T[0] == T0} /. {gamma -> 0.5431799751931238`, b -> 0.08850801132176628`,
      m -> 0.9780307913586779`, r -> 0.8264557187463307`, 
     n -> 14.983207992804674`, p0 -> 0.8`, f0 -> 0.001, T0 -> 0.8`}, {p, f, 
    T}, {t, 0, 72}, c];
```

You only have one parameter unlike the documentation example which has two parameters. Use `T[c][t]`, i.e.,

**EDIT:** corrected parameter value

```
Plot[Evaluate[(T[0.006][t] + {0, .1, -.1}   D[T[c], c][t] /. c -> 0.006) /. 
   s2], {t, 0, 72}, Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is generating an envelope for the function varying by \\[PlusMinus]0.1 its derivative with respect to its parameter.